# Project file from one click install application C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a one click install application that is sat here and now needs some work on it.

I have no project files only the one click install.

Is there a way I can reverse engineer this back into a project file ?

I have tried used .Net reflector however im gaining way too many errors.

Many thanks, 
James

Comment: Telerik's reflector (justDecompiler) is pretty good, but plenty of info is lost during the compile to IL stage. Presuming you didnt run the output through some obfuscation stage that is... What happened to the source?

Comment: @Steve It was a small app that I made a while back for a department in the company... found out today that it is used 1000x over how much it should have been used  ( Designed with around 3 people in mind, being used by about 120 ). So me just being me ended up not saving it over to TFS.But thank you for your suggestion, I shall give that a go now :)

Comment: Ah yes, i know those situations! Good luck

Comment: Cheers! Hopefully it will work this time around.